# Searching within a List of Lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with a list of IDs in each row. I need to be able to search for ID(s) and output the row that contains the ID. I have included sample data below.

I need to be able to input a single ID, or multiple IDs in the search. I have tried the code below but I get the error included at the end of this question.

```
buyers[buyers['customer_list'].str.contains('48184' )]
buyers[buyers['customer_list'].str.contains('48184', '55684')]
```

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[48184, 48184, 64970, 64970], [55684, 72990, 72990, 85673], [55684, 72990, 72990, 85673], [64247, 60131, 60131, 60131], [64544, 64544, 64544, 64544]]})
```

**Error**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-3229146c6a64> in <module>()
----> 1 buyers[buyers['customer_list2'].str.contains( '48184' )]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2680         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2681             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2682             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2683         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2684             return self._getitem_frame(key)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2724             return self._take(indexer, axis=0)
   2725         else:
-> 2726             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2727             return self._take(indexer, axis=1)
   2728 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1325                 if mask.any():
   1326                     raise KeyError('{mask} not in index'
-> 1327                                    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
   1328 
   1329                 return com._values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: '[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan nan nan nan nan nan] not in index'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dataframe constructor and `isin` + `any`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.A.tolist()).isin([48184,55684]).any(1)
Out[29]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply with a lambda function:

```
searchValue = input('ID Search: ')
mask = df['A'].apply(lambda x: int(searchValue) in x)
print(df[mask])

ID Search:  72990
                              A
1  [55684, 72990, 72990, 85673]
2  [55684, 72990, 72990, 85673]
```

if you want to search multiple values from input:

```
searchValue = input('ID Search: ') # input numbers
nums = [int(n) for n in searchValue.split(',')] # list comprehension to int n for n in the input values separated by comma
mask = df['A'].apply(lambda x: any(elem in x for elem in nums)) #  create a mask for any elem in nums and in x which is each row
print(df[mask])

ID Search:  72990,48184
                              A
0  [48184, 48184, 64970, 64970]
1  [55684, 72990, 72990, 85673]
2  [55684, 72990, 72990, 85673]
```